# problem by changing the status of a message to Unseen Seen using IMAP protocol with c #

Tags: c#, imap

I need to change the status of my messages to Unseen and Seen, through telnet I have no problem with the following line of code: IMAP003 UID STORE 25,26 +Flags (\Seen) but when I do it from an object tcp client with c # sending the same line of code I get the following error "Permission denied IMAP003", however with the other commands like reading mails or Fetch command not have problems, I do not know if I have to change any permission on my server , the operating system of my server is suse linux 11 and the program that I manage the email is cyrus imap

PD. sorry if my English is not very good but it is not my native language

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are 'opening' the mailbox with SELECT and not EXAMINE.

Answer (score 0):

You need using this command:

```
"$ SELECT INBOX\r\n"
```

And more inf this examplу https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Simple-IMAP-CLIENT-b249d2e6
But this example contains 2 minor errors:

1. ssl.AuthenticateAsClient("MAIL.*.com");
2. ReceiveResponse("$ LOGIN " +   username + " " + password + "\r\n"); (no spaces needed)